# Symfony form sees entity properties as required without any constraints enforced

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, entity

I am trying to take advantage of Symfony's forms, but the annoying problem so far consists of the fact that form_widget sets a required attribute to the form element even if my entity has no constraints of this kind (non at all so far) on the peer property, instead these properties are doctrine columns that even have "nullable" set to true.

Shouldn't this kind of form elements be UNrequired while no constraint of that kind is enforced within entity?

What can I do to get rid of this attribute?

I have tried this, but is not helping

```
{{ form_widget(form.name, {attr: {class: 'span6 typeahead', required: ''}}) }}
```

or

```
{{ form_widget(form.name, {attr: {class: 'span6 typeahead', required: false}}) }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form builder add attribute "required" and set it to false:

```
$builder
    ->add('name', 'text', array(
            'label' => 'Name:',
            'required' => false
    ));
```

http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/form.html#required

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I realized that it also work the other way (setting required to false in the view), but I just have to get required outside the "attr".

Answer (score 2):

So, if for some reason you don't want to affect the form class by issuing there the unrequired fields there, you can make it work in some particular view like this:

```
{{ form_widget(form.name, {required: false, attr: {class: 'span6 typeahead'}}) }}
```

Note that I have got "required" outside "attr".